# How much traffic has Stack Exchange compared to Yahoo Answers?

Tags: discussion

There is no need for speaking of the qualitative difference between Stack Overflow and [Yahoo Answers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yahoo!_Answers), but I'm curious about the quantity of traffic on both sites.

Yahoo Answers can have more traffic because of the brand behind, the age (five years more than this community) and the generalistic audience it gets but, at the same time, here the quality of the Q&A is very good and the community is growing to cover other stuff which is not only technical.

Comment: Yahoo answers would certainly get comparable numbers, their Google-search presence is very significant. i.e "where is the cigarette lighter in my chevy captiva?" is gonna get you YA result. So general stuff like that. A mostly young site. But Alexa doesn't show Yahoo answers as a separate site. It is all part of yahoo, which is #4 globally. Keep in mind yahoo mail is their biggest thing. 
StackExchange iitself is a portal page, it is ranked about 200.

Comment: You can get a general idea form here - http://www.alexa.com/siteinfo/yahoo.com  . and  here for stackexchange- http://www.alexa.com/siteinfo/stackexchange.com ; stackoverflow - http://www.alexa.com/siteinfo/stackoverflow.com

Comment: Actually, google trends may be the good source of ino - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yahoo!_Answers#Site_statistics

Comment: Sadly the supply of [uninformed reckonings](http://m.youtube.com/watch?v=OQnd5ilKx2Y) is never ending

Comment: Yeah google trends is about popular interest, obviously yahoo is more popular. so here's - http://www.google.com/trends/explore#q=yahoo%20answers%2C%20stackoverflow&cmpt=q

Comment: @Adel: however the falling of Yahoo Answer and the constant grow of SE is interesting to see.

Comment: You may find the quantcast numbers more useful, at least for SE:  https://www.quantcast.com/p-c1rF4kxgLUzNc   For one thing, they roll up the entire network (Alexa is ignoring SO, SF, etc.), plus it's a direct count, while Alexa's is an estimate.

Comment: @Jaydles: is there also quantcast for Yahoo Answers?